# function dispatch in python with varying parameters

Tags: python, dispatch

I have many records of the following type whose attribute values are in string

```
{
  "City": "Pune",
  "Temperature": "32",
  "Unit": "C",
  "Date": "22-11-2012"
}
```

and an associated record descriptor that defines datatype and other attribute properties

```
{
  "City": {
    "datatype": "string"
  },
  "Temperature": {
    "datatype": "double"
  },
  "Unit": {
    "datatype": "string"
  },
  "Date": {
    "datatype": "datetime",
    "dateformat": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "timezone": "UTC"
  }
}
```

I need to convert the record attribute values from string to the appropriate datatype mentioned in the record descriptor

I have a function dispatch dictionary

```
{
   "int" : string_to_int,
   "double": string_to_double,
   "bool": string_to_bool,
   "datetime": string_to_datetime
}

def string_to_int(value):
    <<convert to integer>>

def string_to_double(value):
    <<convert to double>>

def string_to_bool(value):
    <<convert to bool>>

def string_to_datetime(value, date_format, time_zone):
    <<convert to datetime>>
```

By looping through each attribute, how can I do a function dispatch in python to convert the attribute values to appropriate data types? What is the right way to pass additional arguments for datatime conversion without using any if..else logic within the loop?

Comment: would you be open to using a library like marshmallow to solve this? -- https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: What have you tried? You are expected to show some research effort.

Comment: At the very least, store a reference to each converter function, not its name, in your dispatch dictionary. `{ "int": string_to_int, "double": string_to_double, ... }`.

Comment: @chepner sorry I made a mistake while entering

Comment: @PauloScardine I tried creating a convert function def convert2(self, datatype, value, *args, **kwargs):                       
        return self._converter_map[datatype](value, *args, **kwargs)\           
                if datatype in self._converter_map else value

Comment: @MatthewStory I think use of marshmallow library may be an overkill for solving this problem

Comment: @Bharathi obviously you know the problem better than I do, but were I code reviewing this I would question that pretty heavily as this problem is exactly what Marshmallow solves.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good case for actual argument-dispatch, because you want to dispatch on return type and Python's (optional) static typing system does not support that (few languages actually do). Moreover, argument-dispatch is quite an overkill in your case: you already have a well-defined mapping between different data fields and their types.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your specific question, if you modify your type name to function map to store the functions themselves, rather than the name of the function:

```
type_to_function_map = {
   "int" : string_to_int,
   "double": string_to_double,
   "bool": string_to_bool,
   "datetime": string_to_datetime
}
```

And you change the additional arguments to functions like `string_datetime` to be keyword arguments:

```
def string_to_datetime(value, date_format=None, time_zone=None):
    pass
```

You can easily write a function like:

```
def load(payload, schema)
    output = {}
    for k, v in payload.items():
        field_info = schema[k].copy()
        output[k] = type_to_function_map[field_info.pop("datatype")](v, **field_info)

    return output
```

But having said that, there are a number of libraries that do what you're trying to do far better. My personal favorite of these is [`marshmallow`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema

class MySchema(Schema):
    City = fields.String()
    Temperature = fields.Float()
    Unit = fields.String()
    Date = fields.DateTime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
MySchema().loads(data)
```